# How to use clearbits Name To Domain API in python 3

Tags: python

For school research i need to get data from this API. But when i try to use it i get error code 401 (unauthorized) Do you guys know what i'm doing wrong?

i'm using python 3.6 for this.

code:

```
import clearbit 
import urllib.request

from requests import session

payload = {
    'action':'Login',
    'Email': '<login mail>',
    'Password': '<passwd>'
}


clearbit.key = '<My key>'

with session() as c:
    c.post('https://dashboard.clearbit.com', data=payload)
    response = c.get('https://company.clearbit.com/v1/domains/find?name=bseni')
    print(response.text)
```

i hope you guys can help me out with this one.
Documentation: https://clearbit.com/docs#name-to-domain-api

Answer (score 0):

You need to set API key which you can obtain on clearbit website in your profile(you need to register and it is free).
It would be something like:

```
clearbit.key = 'sk_82381594fb01f9erw343243251'
```

Comment: I did do that but i dont want to expose my key so i wrote <My Key>